# Mandar AJAX para uma tabela

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Tenho numa página dados da database inseridos numa tabela:

```
<div class="procurar">
    <input type="text" id="search" onkeypress="mandar()"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<div class="historico">

<table class="table" id="dados_entradas">

<?
    $historico = mysql_query("SELECT ut.nome, ut.contribuinte, en.id_ficha, DATE_FORMAT(en.data_entrada,'%d-%m-%Y') as data
                              FROM entrada en,utilizador ut
                              WHERE en.contribuinte = ut.contribuinte");

    while($linhas = mysql_fetch_array($historico))
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:25%;"><?echo $linhas['nome']; ?></td>
        <td style="width:25%;"><?echo $linhas['contribuinte']; ?> </td>
        <td style="width:25%;"><?echo $linhas['id_ficha']; ?> </td>
        <td style="width:25%;"><?echo $linhas['data']; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?  
    }
?>

</table>
```

E depois eu fiz um input com onkeypress para mandar no AJAX uma consulta, para enviar para esta mesma tabela.

AJAX

```
    function mandar()
{
    var search=$("#search").val();

    $.post("dados-entradas.php",{search:search}, function(data){
        $("#dados_entradas").html(data);

});
}
```

E na página `dados-entradas.php`

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

    $historico = mysql_query("SELECT ut.nome, ut.contribuinte, en.id_ficha, DATE_FORMAT(en.data_entrada,'%d-%m-%Y') as data
                              FROM entrada en,utilizador ut
                              WHERE en.contribuinte = ut.contribuinte
                              AND ut.nome = '$search'");

    while($linhas = mysql_fetch_array($historico))
    {

    echo"<table class='table' id='dados_entradas'>  
    <tr>
        <td style='width:25%;'>".$linhas['nome']."</td>
        <td style='width:25%;'>".$linhas['contribuinte']."</td>
        <td style='width:25%;'>".$linhas['id_ficha']."</td>
        <td style='width:25%;'>".$linhas['data']."</td>
    </tr>
    </table>";


    }
```

O problema é que não retorna valor algum, e desfigura a página inicial toda, excepto a tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repare o seguinte, você declara a tabela da seguinte forma:

```
<table class="table" id="dados_entradas">
```

Porém, na página dados-entrada.php você declara novamente a linha acima, quando deveria declarar apenas as tr's.

Essa é a primeira situação.
Reparei que em seu sql, você coloca para buscar por correspondência exata:

```
ut.nome = '$search'
```

Quando poderia ser:

```
ut.nome LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
```